# Why does QML engine instantiate the same script multiple times?

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

Assume that we have the following JS file:

**logic.js**

```
function Car(){}
```

and these QML files:

**comp1.qml**

```
import 'qrc:/js/logic.js' as Logic

Item{
    property var item: Logic
}
```

**comp2.qml**

```
import 'qrc:/js/logic.js' as Logic

Item{
    property var item: Logic
}
```

If you run and evaluate, you'll see that those `item` properies are not equal. Why?

In my application, in one QML file I `new` an object and would like to check whether it's `instanceof` a constructor function or not, but since those constructor functions aren't equal (because those `Logic`s aren't), `instanceof` operator always returns `false`.

Comment: There is always a one-to-one mapping between qualifiers and JavaScript files. I THINK that's why those `Logic`s are different.

Comment: You might try to use a QML-Singleton-File, where you import the js-file, and have your property. Then you import this singleton instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Code-Behind Implementation Resource](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-resources.html#code-behind-implementation-resource) documentation explains this behaviour:

> Most JavaScript files imported into a QML document are stateful implementations for the QML document importing them. In these cases, each instance of the QML object type defined in the document requires a separate copy of the JavaScript objects and state in order to behave correctly.
>
> The default behavior when importing JavaScript files is to provide a unique, isolated copy for each QML component instance. If that JavaScript file does not import any resources or modules with a .import statement, its code will run in the same scope as the QML component instance and consequently can access and manipulate the objects and properties declared in that QML component. Otherwise, it will have its own unique scope, and objects and properties of the QML component should be passed to the functions of the JavaScript file as parameters if they are required.

The solution is to put `.pragma library` at the top of your JavaScript file. This will allow it to be shared by several QML files.

The next section, [Shared JavaScript Resources (Libraries)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-resources.html#shared-javascript-resources-libraries) goes into more detail about this.

Comment: there is a current Bug (Qt5.13), so that ".pragma library" oftentimes does not work, especially together with Qt Quick Compiler

Comment: If there is a bug report for it, you should put it here so people can check when it's fixed.

Comment: good point, here you go: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-42102 it says Qt5.4, but I experience it with Qt5.13. Note that singletons are affected in the same way (no bug for that found yet)